# Guice provider based on injected class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am trying to inject an object into the constructor of the class that is created based on retained annotations on the injected class. I can create the object itself simply enough with a `Provider`, but I need to obtain the class that is currently being injected.

The abstract `MyClass` and a basic `MyClassImpl` implementation:

```
public abstract class MyClass {} //ignoring constructor

@Annotation("value")
public class MyClassImpl extends MyClass {

    @Inject
    private MyClass(MyService service, MyObject object) {
        super(service, object);
    }

}
```

The service providing instances and containing the `Injector`:

```
public class MyService {

    private final Injector injector;

    public <T extends MyClass> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        return injector.getInstance(clazz);
    }

}
```

My goal is to set up the module such that I can inject an instance of `MyObject` that is created using information from the annotation, such as having an id be `value` in the above example.

A sketchy solution is to save the class currently being injected as a variable in `MyService`. The module is created in the constructor, so I can get it from and this should meet my needs well enough. However, I would think there would be some way to get the class currently being injected.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to match an existing MyObject with that ID from somewhere? Or is it ok for MyClassImpl to set the ID after receiving it?

Comment: MyObject would be created with the id; it's a unique instance. In reality, there are about 5 different variables being set in this manner. MyObject is actually following a builder pattern where the annotations apply default values that can be changed or built upon once passed into the constructor.